# How to listen other actor's event in unreal engine?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

It's easy to listen events of actor self like collision, overlap etc.

But is there any way to subscribe other actor's event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to subscribe to the events made by UE but it's very easy to implement it with blueprint interface or event dispatcher. You could create a blueprint interface function and call it when your actor event is triggered then implement that function with the actor you want to be listening and there you go, when the event is occurred the function you are implementing starts.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/Blueprints/UserGuide/Types/Interface/

Comment: but how do I know which actor is listening my events?

Comment: Everyone that implements the blueprint interface is listening, you should only implement it if you want the actor to be listening.

Comment: Sounds great. I'm interested that how does Unreal know which object implements that interface.

Comment: I don't know the unreal specific but if you want to achieve the same result you should use the node: 'GetAllActorsWithInterface'